# If $G$ and $H$ are groups, show that $G \cong H \iff dG \cong dH$ and $\frac{G}{dG} \cong \frac{H}{dH}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$  and $H$ are abelian groups, show that $G \cong H \iff dG \cong dH$ and $\frac{G}{dG} \cong \frac{H}{dH}$, where $dG$ and $dH$ are the divisible subgroups generated by all the divisible subgroups of $G,H$, respectively.

I was going to prove this by saying that $G = dG \oplus R_G$ for some reduced subgroup $R_g \leq G$ and likewise for $H$, but then I realized that this only holds if the groups we are talking about are abelian. (A reduced group is a group with no divisible subgroups).

Anyway, for the forward implication, if we have a an isomorphism $\alpha:G \rightarrow H$ then I believe that without too much trouble that I can show that the restriction of $\alpha$ to $dG$ and the induced homomorphism on $\frac{G}{dG}$ are also isomorphisms. I'm having trouble with the reverse statement though. Can anyone help me out a bit?? Thanks!

Comment: If $G$ is not abelian, then it is not necessarily true that $dG$ is itself divisible (taking it to be the subgroup generated by the divisible elements): $\mathbb{Q}*\mathbb{Q}$ (free product) is clearly generated by divisible elements, but not every element is divisible, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I forgot to mention that G is divisible. Dang, you're good!

Comment: No, that can’t be what you forgot to mention, because if $G$ is divisible, then $dG$ would be all of $G$ and there would be nothing to prove. You mean, you forgot to mention they are abelian? But if you *are* supposed to assume they are abelian, then what is the point of your second paragraph?

Comment: Hm... yeah It doesn't say assume the groups are abelian, yet the question is from the chapter on abelian groups. Alas, I didn't like the question much anyway. Thanks dude you're the best!